# String Index in Array

Tags: typescript

In the TypeScript [docs](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interfaces%20in%20TypeScript&referringTitle=TypeScript%20Documentation), it gives this example of a array interface:

```
interface Dictionary {
[index: string]: string;
}
```

I don't get this.  I thought associative arrays such as `myArray['First']` were not good practice.

Can someone explain this or give me an example of using this interface?

Comment: What makes you think such arrays are bad practice? One use case that comes to mind is localization - an associative array is a fine way to map a placeholder string to a translated string.

Comment: Because TsLint give me this when I tried it: object access via a string literal is disallowed.

Comment: That error talks about a *string literal* (using a predetermined and hardcoded string index such as `'First'`), not a *string-typed index* in general. The string literal case can be problematic because not all tools understand it and they can skip over it when you use IDE features like "Find Usages"/"Find All References" or try to rename/refactor a property.

Comment: I see.  So is there a better way to do this? Or just ignore the warning in this case?

Comment: You can disable that rule around the lines where you actually need to use this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative arrays are not a good idea if you use them as *arrays*. The associative array is great for implementing a hash map, or dictionary.

For more explanation of the dictionary use case check out this example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array#Example